Pyhton fastapi problem in APScheduler Run time of job was missed
I faced a problem. I wrote a program using the Python language and needed to run jobs at a specific time, so I used the apscheduler library and the "cron" feature.found every time, job is missed on time
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from fastapi import FastAPI

import backgound_operation.backup_devices as backup_devices
import db.models as models
from db.database import engine
from routers import authentication, device, user

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

#scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 15*60})
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 3600})
#scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(_: FastAPI):
    print("app started....")
    scheduler.start()
    yield
    print("app stopped...")
    scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
app.include_router(authentication.router)
app.include_router(user.router)
app.include_router(device.router)


def backup_job():
    backup_devices.backup_devices()


scheduler.add_job(
    id="job1",
    func=backup_job,
    misfire_grace_time=3600,
    trigger="cron",
    hour=7,
    minute=32,
    second=0,
)

and I get the error as missed job by some seconds as

Run time of job "backup_job (trigger: cron[hour='23', minute='0', second='0'], next run at: 2024-07-17 23:00:00 WAT)" was missed by 0:00:04.137012

